# How do I ensure legacy Docker packages are uninstalled before installing the new packages?

Tags: docker, puppet

We have some older servers with the legacy Docker package installed from the distribution package repository. Either from manual installs

```
$ yum install docker
```

Or older manifests

```
package { 'docker': 
    ensure => present,
}
```

We want to migrate to the [official Docker repository and packages](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/) via the "supported" [puppetlabs-docker](https://forge.puppet.com/puppetlabs/docker) module.

```
include docker
```

However, the legacy Docker packages are not removed or otherwise managed by this new module!

```
[vagrant@localhost ~]$ sudo -i puppet apply -e 'include docker'
Notice: Compiled catalog for localhost.localdomain in environment production in 0.42 seconds
Notice: /Stage[main]/Docker::Repos/Yumrepo[docker]/ensure: created
Error: Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install docker-ce' returned 1: Error: docker-ce conflicts with 2:docker-1.13.1-75.git8633870.el7.centos.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
Error: /Stage[main]/Docker::Install/Package[docker]/ensure: change from 'purged' to 'present' failed: Execution of '/bin/yum -d 0 -e 0 -y install docker-ce' returned 1: Error: docker-ce conflicts with 2:docker-1.13.1-75.git8633870.el7.centos.x86_64
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

How do we make sure the legacy package is removed *before* installing the new package?

Comment: Just run `yum remove docker` on all your hosts? Modify your puppet manifests to have `ensure => absent` and re-run puppet?

Comment: Really this is a problem with the Docker RPM metadata neglecting to set the `obsoletes` tag.

Comment: Although I think this is a reasonable issue to raise against the module, I see that it does not appear to have been received warmly over there.  There *are* one or two things that they could do to make the module more friendly to this case, such as not tromping on the `docker` package title when the actual name of the package they want to manage differs.

Comment: @MattSchuchard ooo, this sounds interesting... can you tell me more? (I'm going to google, too, but I'd like to have enough info to file a bug!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to start by ensuring the legacy package is absent.

```
package { 'docker':
    ensure => absent,
}
```

But, you can't use `Package['docker']`, because the new puppetlabs-docker module already declares it. You have to do something like this:

```
package { 'legacy-docker':
    ensure => absent,
    name => 'docker',
}
```

There are a number of legacy [prerequisite packages](https://docs.docker.com/install/linux/docker-ce/centos/#uninstall-old-versions) that also need to be removed, too.

```
package { [
    'docker-client',
    'docker-client-latest',
    'docker-common',
    'docker-latest',
    'docker-latest-logrotate',
    'docker-logrotate',
    'docker-selinux',
    'docker-engine-selinux',
    'docker-engine',
]:
    ensure => absent,
}
```

So, all together, this ordering seems to work implicitly.

```
package { 'legacy-docker':
    ensure => absent,
    name => 'docker',
}

package { [
    'docker-client',
    'docker-client-latest',
    'docker-common',
    'docker-latest',
    'docker-latest-logrotate',
    'docker-logrotate',
    'docker-selinux',
    'docker-engine-selinux',
    'docker-engine',
]:
    ensure => absent,
}

include docker
```

Actually, this seems to cause problems on subsequent runs of the manifest... common second-level dependencies are removed!

```
Error: Execution of '/bin/rpm -e container-selinux-2.68-1.el7.noarch' returned 1: error: Failed dependencies:
        container-selinux >= 2.9 is needed by (installed) docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64
Error: /Stage[main]/Profile::Docker/Package[docker-selinux]/ensure: change from '2:2.68-1.el7' to 'absent' failed: Execution of '/bin/rpm -e container-selinux-2.68-1.el7.noarch' returned 1: error: Failed dependencies:
        container-selinux >= 2.9 is needed by (installed) docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64
Error: Execution of '/bin/rpm -e container-selinux-2.68-1.el7.noarch' returned 1: error: Failed dependencies:
        container-selinux >= 2.9 is needed by (installed) docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64
Error: /Stage[main]/Profile::Docker/Package[docker-engine-selinux]/ensure: change from '2:2.68-1.el7' to 'absent' failed: Execution of '/bin/rpm -e container-selinux-2.68-1.el7.noarch' returned 1: error: Failed dependencies:
        container-selinux >= 2.9 is needed by (installed) docker-ce-18.06.1.ce-3.el7.x86_64
```

Well, the package resource doesn't have a `refreshonly` kind of property, so we need to resort to an exec resource. Ugh.

```
package { 'legacy-docker':
    ensure => absent,
    name => 'docker',
    notify => Exec['autoremove'],
}

exec { 'autoremove':
    command => '/usr/bin/yum -y autoremove',
    refreshonly => true,
}

include docker
```

This is... reasonable? The only thing might be ordering, you might explore explicit resource ordering using `->`.

Comment: Do verify that that is not removing and reinstalling the Docker package(s) on every run.  I can think of reasons why it might do, but so long as doesn't, I think that's about as clean a solution as you can hope for.